# Global Git configuration ignored

Tags: git, configuration

I configured globally Git with the following:

```
git config --global user.name "My Name"
git config --global user.email "me@email.com"
```

If I check the settings, everything seems to be OK:

```
~$ git config -l
user.name=My Name
user.email=me@email.com
```

But when I start a new project (or checkout another one and commit something), it doesn't take this configuration into account:

```
~$ mkdir test
~$ cd test
~$ git init
~$ touch testfile
~$ git add testfile
~$ git commit -m "This is a test"
[master (root-commit) b090816] This is a test
 Author: login <login@localdomain>
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 testfile
```

I tried to set up local config, but it doesn't work either:

```
~$ git config user.name "My Name"
~$ git config --local -l
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
user.name=My Name

~$ touch anotherfile
~$ git add anotherfile
~$ git commit -m "This is another test"
[master 7f6a085] This is another test
 Author: login <login@localdomain>
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 anotherfile
```

My Git version is 2.5.1 and I am running on GNU/Linux.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you check your repo's git config?

Comment: Is there another command to check that that the `git config --local -l` I already posted?

Comment: I don't normally use the `--local` option. Maybe there's a difference? Although thinking about it now, I doubt it.

Comment: Do you have `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME`, `GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL`, `GIT_COMMITTER_NAME`, `GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL` among the env variables?

Comment: That's it, thanks! I unset these variables in my `.bashrc` and now my Git configuration is taken into account.